# difference between npm job and command line

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, npm-scripts

I've set up webpack for my webextension.
In the `package.json`, I have defined the following script:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
},
```

so webpack can be started with one of these two options:

- npm run start
- webpack --config webpack.config.js

But while the `npm run start` works fine, the direct call to  `webpack --config webpack.config.js` fails.
Here is my code: https://github.com/lhk/webextensions-webpack-boilerplate

You can reproduce the problem with the following steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/lhk/webextensions-webpack-boilerplate
cd webextensions-webpack-boilerplate
npm install
tsc -p tsconfig.json
webpack --config webpack.config.js
```

The error message is:

```
clean-webpack-plugin: /home/lhk/.local/share/Trash/files/temp.2/webextensions-webpack-boilerplate/dist has been removed.
(node:21823) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
/usr/lib/node_modules/webpack/lib/Chunk.js:827
        throw new Error(
        ^

Error: Chunk.entrypoints: Use Chunks.groupsIterable and filter by instanceof Entrypoint instead
    at Chunk.get (/usr/lib/node_modules/webpack/lib/Chunk.js:827:9)
    at /home/lhk/.local/share/Trash/files/temp.2/webextensions-webpack-boilerplate/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:176:48
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /home/lhk/.local/share/Trash/files/temp.2/webextensions-webpack-boilerplate/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:171:18
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/usr/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:7:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/usr/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at Compilation.seal (/usr/lib/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1215:27)
    at hooks.make.callAsync.err (/usr/lib/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:541:17)
    at _err0 (eval at create (/usr/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:11:1)
    at _addModuleChain (/usr/lib/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1066:12)
    at processModuleDependencies.err (/usr/lib/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:982:9)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
```

System information:

- node version is: v8.12.0
- npm version is: 6.4.1
- operating system is: ubuntu 18.04 (64bit)

Comment: When running `webpack --config webpack.config.js` directly via your CLI, you are utilizing the globally installed version of _webpack_. When you run `npm run start`, _npm_ is utilizing the locally installed version of _webpack_ i.e. the version found inside the `webextensions-webpack-boilerplate/node_modules/.bin` directory. So perhaps there are version differences between the globally and locally installed _webpack_.

Comment: You can verify which versions of _webpack_ are installed both locally and globally by running: **1)** `cd webextensions-webpack-boilerplate` **2)** `npm ls --depth 0 webpack` (for local version) **3)** `npm ls -g --depth 0 webpack` (for global version).